# Reacti18next store current language on redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist, react-i18next

im trying to use react-i18next with redux.

What im mostly doing is I init the i18n instance and try to store the current language in the redux, sadly there's a problem, im using redux-persist to persist state, so if I close and open the app the redux-persist loads all the data back into cache, since this process might take some time redux-persist as a way of making the app wait for the cache to be rehydrated, it can be done by placing the PersistGate with the loading prop and which I do as stated in the code below.

Sadly since the i18n instance is imported in the top of the file it wont wait at all for the store to be ready so it runs right after the app is opened and tries to use the store which is not ready.

Any idea of how I can hold the i18n instance until the store is ready?

i18n.js file

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';

import store from 'Api/store';
import { setLanguageTag, sincronizeSettings } from 'Api/store/actions';
import { languages } from 'Base/config.json';

const translations = {
  en: { translation: require('Assets/translations/en.json') },
  pt: { translation: require('Assets/translations/pt.json') },
};

const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: async (callback) => {
    const storedLanguageTag = store.getState().settings.data?.languageTag;
    if (storedLanguageTag) {
      return callback(storedLanguageTag);
    }

    const { languageTag: deviceBestAvailableLanguageTag } = RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(
      languages.available,
    );

    const currentLanguageTag = deviceBestAvailableLanguageTag || languages.default;

    store.dispatch(setLanguageTag(currentLanguageTag));
    store.dispatch(sincronizeSettings());

    callback(currentLanguageTag);
  },
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

const i18n = i18next.createInstance();
i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: languages.default,
    resources: translations,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

index.js where I call the i18n instance(**cutted out unnecessary code**)

```js
....
import 'Api/i18n';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<Launch />}>
            <ReduxNetworkProvider pingInBackground>
              <AppContainer />
            </ReduxNetworkProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered here on the appropriate github repository: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1040